# deployerConfigContext.xml has no effect

Tags: spring, maven, cas

I tried to get a CAS-server up and running using https://github.com/apereo/cas-overlay-template for a side project (I'm a student), but I have never used maven or spring before.

I'm trying to hook my own IPersonAttributeDao into the CAS-server. However, when I put my deployerConfigContext.xml under `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/`, nothing actually changed when I repackaged (using the build script) and deployed to tomcat8. (Yes, I did restart tomcat).

Below the contents of my deployerConfigContent.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <bean id="authenticationManager" class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.AuthenticationManagerImpl">
        <property name="credentialsToPrincipalResolvers">
            <list>
                <bean id="primaryPrincipalResolver"
                      class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.principal.PersonDirectoryPrincipalResolver">
                    <property name="attributeRepository" ref="attributeRepository"/>
                </bean>
                <bean class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.principal.UsernamePasswordCredentialsToPrincipalResolver">
                    <property name="attributeRepository" ref="attributeRepository"/>
                </bean>

                <bean class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.principal.HttpBasedServiceCredentialsToPrincipalResolver">
                    <property name="attributeRepository" ref="attributeRepository"/>
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="authenticationHandlers">
            <list>
                <bean id="primaryAuthenticationHandler"
                      class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.AcceptUsersAuthenticationHandler">
                    <property name="users">
                        <map>
                            <!-- Login stays the default casuser:Mellon, no idea why -->
                            <entry key="test" value="1234"/>
                        </map>
                    </property>
                </bean>
                <!-- DO NOT EVER PUT THIS BEAN IN PRODUCTION!!! -->
                <bean class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.handler.support.SimpleTestUsernamePasswordAuthenticationHandler"/>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

   <!-- <bean id="attributeRepository" class="class.i.am.trying.to.hook.in">
    </bean>-->

    <!-- This doesn't seem to work -->
    <bean id="attributeRepository"
          class="org.jasig.services.persondir.support.StubPersonAttributeDao">
        <property name="backingMap">
            <map>
                <entry key="uid" value="uid" />
                <entry key="eduPersonAffiliation" value="eduPersonAffiliation" />
                <entry key="groupMembership" value="groupMembership" />
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

What am I missing?

UPDATE:

I reread the documentation (https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.0.x/), and found that deployerConfigContext.xml was supposed to be in `resources`, and not in `webapp/WEB-INF` as I found on the internet. I moved it, and now I'm finally getting errors in the log (which means the file is being read).

Error below:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.jasig.cas.authentication.PolicyBasedAuthenticationManager] for bean with name 'authenticationManager' defined in class path resource [deployerConfigContext.xml]
```

I found a reference to `PolicyBasedAuthenticationManager` in the docs, but trying that gave the same error (with the other classname ofcourse).

Comment: probably you have version problem in your CAS server. check dependencies to have the exact noted class.

Answer (score 1):

> Bean classes of enabled beans must be deployed in bean archives.
>
> A library jar, EJB jar, application client jar or rar archive is a
>   bean archive if it has a file named beans.xml in the META-INF
>   directory. The WEB-INF/classes directory of a war is a bean archive if
>   there is a file named beans.xml in the WEB-INF directory of the war. A
>   directory in the JVM classpath is a bean archive if it has a file
>   named beans.xml in the META-INF directory.

One suggestion, if you are using Spring, you can also set @Annotation to define beans.

Comment: Turns out the `deployerConfigContext.xml` should be put in another directory than I found on the internet (maybe it changed with the last CAS version?). Now I get an error in my logs (see updated question).

Comment: @Soronbe can you declare the missing bean and see if it solves this issue.

Comment: @Soronbe if you are implementing a system with CAS and planning to use Spring, Spring Security, maybe checkout thishttps://simonlzn.github.io/2016/11/20/CAS-with-Spring-Security.html.

Comment: Turns out I should use `org.apereo` instead of `org.jasig` when using version 5. It's still not working, but atleast I got errors I understand now. Granted you the bounty for your efforts. (edit: Just noticed I can only reward the bounty in 22 hours)

Comment: Thank you! I have had some experience with implementing my own CAS system and using Spring framework. If you need further help, you can still contact me.